# ClusterMarkers Ionic 2/3 Native GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, ionic3

Someone soon worked ClusterMarkers to host a lot of 2/3 ionic markers with the native GoogleMaps plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how to add a Marker to you map. Care you need to build you map first.

```
addMarker() {

// costum image
//let image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: this.map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: this.map.getCenter()
  //,icon: image
});

let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";

this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

}
```